# Missing script: "dev" while running the command "npm run dev"

Tags: vue.js, npm, installation, package

Trying to create vue.js project and trying to run the project but getting error " Missing script: "dev"".
Attached the complete error occurring.

> npm ERR! Missing script: "dev"
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
> npm ERR!   npm run
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\someone\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-04-18T09_03_34_029Z-debug-0.log

I am new to this and unable to find the solution. below is the package.json file

```
{
  "name": "scirtem-front-end",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "run-p type-check build-only",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "build-only": "vite build",
    "type-check": "vue-tsc --noEmit",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .vue,.js,.jsx,.cjs,.mjs,.ts,.tsx,.cts,.mts --fix --ignore-path .gitignore",
    "format": "prettier --write src/"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.3.5",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.10.4",
    "element-plus": "^2.3.1",
    "hover.css": "^2.3.2",
    "pinia": "^2.0.32",
    "sass": "^1.59.3",
    "vue": "^3.2.47",
    "vue-axios": "^3.5.2",
    "vue-router": "^4.1.6",
    "vue2-filters": "^0.14.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rushstack/eslint-patch": "^1.2.0",
    "@types/node": "^18.14.2",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.0.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx": "^3.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^7.1.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^11.0.2",
    "@vue/tsconfig": "^0.1.3",
    "eslint": "^8.34.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.9.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "prettier": "^2.8.4",
    "typescript": "~4.8.4",
    "vite": "^4.1.4",
    "vue-tsc": "^1.2.0"
  }
  
}
```

I tried installing npm with  **npm install**  . npm is getting installed but while I run npm run dev i get the above error.

Comment: Did you maybe run the command outside of your work directory? Such as created the project but forgot to navigate into the directory `cd ./scirtem-front-end` first?

Comment: No its in the same directory.  PS C:\Users\someone\Downloads\scirtem-frontend (1)>

Comment: Changed the directory and tried                                           PS C:\Users\someone\scirtem-frontend (1)> npm run dev
npm ERR! Missing script: "dev"
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\someone\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-04-18T09_24_16_346Z-debug-0.log
PS C:\Users\someone\scirtem-frontend (1)>

Comment: the error appears when there is a package.json file but no "dev" script is found in the `scripts` json property.  if you're running from the correct directory and the package.json has `{ "scripts": { "dev": "..." } }` where `...` could be a valid or even invalid script, you should at least see npm give a different error as long as "dev" script is there.  you could try linking a github repo to have others confirm the script for you, but besides that there's nothing more that can be said to properly run the command.